# Excel 'LET' function not working using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I am working on automating a few processes using Openpyxl as it is the most widely(maybe only) library used that has support for Excel formulas.

I have used a variety of functions in formulas in the program and they work pretty well. However, the `LET` function leads to 2 scenarios:

When I use it as is ie:

```
...... # boilerplate code
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "=LET(MYVAL,\"Boogawooga\",MYVAL)"
```

It updates the formula as `=@LET(MYVAL,"Boogawooga",MYVAL)` and I get a `#NAME?` error on the cell(s).

When I prefix it with `_xlfn` ie:

```
...... # boilerplate code
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "=_xlfn.LET(MYVAL,\"Boogawooga\",MYVAL)"
```

I get the following error upon opening the excel doc, and the cell(s) with the formula are empty:
[image]

Using:

- openpyxl==3.0.7
- python 3.6
- Excel 365(`Let` function works on the file directly so it's not an old version issue)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Luckily I managed to find a solution. Posting it now

Comment: Hi @Ebj, Good job! I'm happy to know something new. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

It looks like, in addition to `_xlfn`, you might need the `_xlpm` prefix for variables!

This works:

```
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "=_xlfn.LET(_xlpm.MYVAL,\"Boogawooga\",_xlpm.MYVAL)"
```